# ERROR kubebootstrap: WORKER PANICKED: ingresses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User cannot list resource "ingresses" in API group "networking.k8s.io"

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, ambassador, k8s-serviceaccount, k8s-rolebinding

I am currently encountering an issue with my Amazon EKS cluster that hosts Lucidworks Fusion. To start with I had an Amazon EKS **v1.18** cluster that I then upgraded to **v1.19** which all went well. I also had **ingress-nginx-3.7.1** running in my cluster that I then upgraded to **ingress-nginx-4.0.19** everything still seemed to operate properly at that point. That said once I upgraded my cluster to **v1.20**, when draining my pods and restarting them in my new worker nodes all pods restarted properly except my **Ambassador** pod which is stuck in a *CrashLoopBackOff* state now. I looked into this pod's logs and found the following error:

```
2022/04/08 14:00:35 ERROR(s): kubebootstrap: WORKER PANICKED: ingresses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:sandbox1:sandbox1-ambassador" cannot list resource "ingresses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" in the namespace "sandbox1"
```

Does anyone know what this means ? I believe this is telling me something related to permissions but I am not exactly sure. Also I would like to understand what caused this issue, was it upgrading my EKS cluster to v1.20 or was it upgrading ingress-nginx or something entirely different ? Lastly I'd like to understand how I can solve this issue and get this pod running properly again ? Any help is welcomed.

Comment: This is an issue with RBAC and it states very clearly that at this point service account `sandbox1-ambassador` does not have permissions to view `ingress` resource. Most correct solution to me is to upgrade `ambassador` itself via `helm` if it was installed this way. If it's not an option, then you need to find `role` related to `abmassador` in `sandbox1` namespace and correct it so it has `ingress` resource. [This is how it looks in general](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging into this further I found that in order to fix this issue I needed to edit the *sandbox1-ambassador* role. So I executed the following command

```
kubectl edit role sandbox1-ambassador
```

and I appended the following to this configuration:

```
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - get
```

Once I saved these changes and closed the edit session I restarted the Ambassador pod and everything started working properly again.